# Make two elements to have the same width with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have two elements (a paragraph and a img) inside a link element and i want the paragraph to be the same width as the img, i tried doing `display: inline-block;` and a couple other things but cant seem to get it to work. can anyone help?

```html
<li>
    <a href="https://store.steampowered.com/app/4000/Garrys_Mod/" target="_blank" >
        <img src="/Photos/garrysmod.jpg">
        <p>Garrys Mod is a physics sandbox game in which you can do allmost anything you want, including playing hide and seek, fighting monster, fighting eachother, escape from jail, and much more</p>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: you can give img,p{width:50%}

Answer (score 0):

Edited/changed after comment (the question wasn't clear about this):

Apply `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column;` to the link, plus an optional `width` setting to the parent container (`ul`), and (also optionally) `text-align: justify` to the `p` tag to make the text align also to the right border:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 400px; /* any value here, or no value to fill the horizontally available space  */
}

li a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

li a p {
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="https://store.steampowered.com/app/4000/Garrys_Mod/" target="_blank">
      <img src="/Photos/garrysmod.jpg">
      <p>Garrys Mod is a physics sandbox game in which you can do allmost anything you want, including playing hide and seek, fighting monster, fighting eachother, escape from jail, and much more</p>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this seems to show the text next to the image instead of underneath

Comment: @HamishMcdonald Yes, that's how I understood your question

Comment: I changed my answer now, added `flex-direction: column` to the link and an *optional* `width` setting, plus `text-align: justify;` to the `p` tag to make the text also align to the right border.

Comment: this seems to cause the image width to go really wide instead of making the text the same width as the img

Comment: @HamishMcdonald The image width is determined by the width of the *parent* element (`ul`), so you simply set that width to whatever value you want and have image and text with the same width.

Answer (score 0):

I have given you an example below to learn from.

You should look into flex. It's just an easy way to control content. There is no actual purpose for it here, but I still gave the link container the flex property, because you would probably want to align the content later (e.g. align-items: center).

Read up on flexbox, good luck!

```css
.link {
  display: flex;
}

.link img {
  width: 50%;
}

.link p {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
    <div>
        <a class="link" href="https://store.steampowered.com/app/4000/Garrys_Mod/" target="_blank" >
            <img src="https://cdn.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/4000/ss_ff27d52a103d1685e4981673c4f700b860cb23de.600x338.jpg?t=1663621793">
            <p>Garrys Mod is a physics sandbox game in which you can do allmost anything you want, including playing hide and seek, fighting monster, fighting eachother, escape from jail, and much more</p>
        </a>
    </div>
```